# OpenLDAP Authentication in Mixed Enviroment

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mac-osx, openldap, openbsd

I am preparing to setup a small network with single sign on capability provided by and OpenLDAP server that runs on OpenBSD 5.3.  Currently, I am able authenticate an Ubuntu 13.04 client against the server, but for some reason I am having trouble authenticating on my OS X client.  I've used the directory utility to connect to my server, and it seems that I am able to successfully communicate with the server, but not authenticate.  I know this may seem vauge, but I am new to administering OS X.  Help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I'm fighting through this myself as we speak. One of the things you must add on the Ubuntu side, according to my research, is a Kerberos KDC. There is some great documentation on setting one of these up here: https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/kerberos-ldap.html .

Comment: While Kerberos gets along very will with OpenLDAP, and I would recommend it, it is by no means required.

Comment: The OP asked how to authenticate using Apple's Directory Utility, which I am still struggling with. DU attempts to do a SASL bind. From the error logs, I'm still trying to determine which mechanism is used. Any advice would be appreciated.